# iOS touchesBegan being overridden by UIScrollView. Not a delay issue. Can't use gesture recognizer in this case

Tags: ios, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0, touchesbegan

So I read quite a bit, but still I can't find the solution.

I have a `UIViewController` which is creating (programatically) a `UIScrollView`, which Contains a `UIView` and a `UIImage`. The `UIView` lies on top of the rest.

This `UIView` generates some `UIImageViews` which I need to get feedback from when tapped. I need to know which image was tapped by getting their tags. That's why I can't use **gesture recognizer**, since it can only be called on one view.

If I call this:

```
- (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    NSLog(@"tag=%@", [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", touch.view.tag]);

}
```

On the view (called **`GraphView`**, which has it's own class) I get what I need. Still, I need to do this from the **ViewController** side because I have to open modal window, navigation controllers, etc... If I use that same code on the **ViewController** nothing happens. If I disable User Interaction on the `UIScrollView` it works. If I disable the delay on the `UIScrollView` nothing happens. No matter how long you press you get nothing. `touchesBegan` doesn't get called at all even if the delay is enabled.

Here's the part of the **implementation** of the **ViewController** where I generate the Views:

```
// ScrollView
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 480, 320);
myScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
myScrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
myScrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = YES;
myScrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = YES;
myScrollView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
myScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(SCROLLVIEW_WIDTH, SCROLLVIEW_HEIGHT);
myScrollView.delegate = self;
[self.view addSubview:myScrollView];

// Add UIImage for background
UIImageView *backgroundGraph = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake (0,0,SCROLLVIEW_WIDTH,SCROLLVIEW_HEIGHT)];
backgroundGraph.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"graph_background.png"];
backgroundGraph.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
[myScrollView addSubview:backgroundGraph];
//[self.view addSubview:backgroundGraph];
[backgroundGraph release];

// Add View for Graph.
GraphView *graphViewC = [[GraphView alloc] init];
self.graphView = graphViewC;
graphView.tag = 200;
graphView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
graphView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, SCROLLVIEW_WIDTH, SCROLLVIEW_HEIGHT);
graphView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[myScrollView addSubview:graphView];
//[self.view addSubview:graphView];
```

**.h** file on **ViewController** looks like this:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class GraphView;

@interface TrackingViewController : UIViewController <UIScrollViewDelegate> {
    UIScrollView *myScrollView;

    GraphView *graphView;

    int someNum;

#define SCROLLVIEW_HEIGHT 273
#define SCROLLVIEW_WIDTH 599

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) GraphView *graphView;

- (void) openModal;
//- (void)handleSingleTap:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer;

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIScrollView *myScrollView;

@end
```

As always, I am thankful to everyone who can help with any ideas(and I've gotten a lot of help here always, so thanks in advance :-) ).

Comment: Why can't you add a gesture recognizer to each view needing tap detection? Also, you could set up a delegation api between the view and the view controller to pass along touches.

Comment: Well, I read something in some post and probably got missguided. But you're probably right, I will try that. If it works I'll let you know so you can post this as an answer and I can give you a vote. Thanks.

Comment: Actually, Andrew. The code I have which generates the images is on a UIView subclass. If I could have detected the touches from the controller it would be easier. In this case I would have to add the gesture recognizers on the UIView which then would make it hard to trigger the method to open a modal which is on the ViewController for that UIView. This ViewController is not the main one, so I don't have a delegate file for it. Any ideas? I guess I could call the method of that UIViewController from the App Delegate... makes sense?

Comment: Andrew, post and answer and I'll give you a vote. It's all working now. Did use the App Delegate to call the Modal. All images are responding to touch. Sometimes the answer is right in front of you but you can't see because you're thinking too hard. That's why testing your ideas or asking questions to other devs is so important. ;-)